# Windows installation disc won't boot

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, dvd

I have bought an ubuntu pre-installed laptop and want to remove ubuntu and replace with windows 8.1 x64 pro..
It has UEFI and in GPT.. disabled secure boot.. but there is no fast boot or legacy boot options..

Problem is i can't boot my windows 8.1 installation disc.. It says an error 0xc0000225.

Here is what i did so far:
 - Boot Ubuntu Live USB
 - Removed all partitions and convert GPT into MBR
 - Disabled Secure boot on UEFI
 - After that boot my windows 8 installation. still got error

What should i do? is there no way of installing windows 8 on my laptop? or is my laptop only for Ubuntu?

Comment: laptop manufacturer and model?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8.1 x64 dvd won't boot on UEFI pre-installed Ubuntu laptop](http://superuser.com/questions/791987/windows-8-1-x64-dvd-wont-boot-on-uefi-pre-installed-ubuntu-laptop)

Answer (score 0):

Are you confident about Windows 8 disk? Does it work with other PCs. If your DVD disk is copied, then probably there is something wrong with your disk. Probably your disk is missing a file.

You should also check whether your first boot option is set to DVD drive, not hard disk or USB.

you can also try to change your boot mode. Don't select only UEFI in the boot settings. I can't specify the options because all mainboards are not of same look.

Comment: No. my disc is fine and working with all my PCs and Laptops.. Im also using im using an external DVD drive and overide the boot to it.. after i booted the DVD i will get a Windows boot Manager error. I also tried my old windows 7 and XP disc but they wont boot because its not a UEFI bootable. Well, thats what i learned so far..

Furthermore, theres no more options for booting here, because all i can see is the secureboot option, and the boot devices and no more.. i dont know whats wrong with this laptop because its very different from the others i have used..

Comment: Which brand you're using buddy? Then maybe your motherboard is optimized for stupid Ubuntu (I'm not sure). But there must be an option to boot from Windows if the manufacturer don't try to stop using Windows intentionally. By the way, does Windows disk work while running from ubuntu?